# changing a string to a int in flutter by using tostring but flutter show an error

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to make a textfield form for the user to input the some numbers in it. then I want to use the number and send it into Duration class. this Duration class can only accept int but my textfield form is text, I cannot change it into int. after some research it say can use to string but flutter tells me the instance member of hourController can't be accessed in an initializer. can any one help.
this is my code

```
final hourController =TextEditingController(); 
//this is the textformfield that I use I name it 
//hourController. here the user will input numbers 
//only. 
int durationhour = hourController;
hourController = durationhour.toString();
```

Comment: where are you trying to access its content? Also you are trying to assign to an int the hourController which is an object.

Answer (score 1):

this is your text editing controller

```
final hourController = TextEditingController();
```

this is how string convert to integer

```
int durationhour = int.parse(hourController.text);
```

and this is how you can convert integer to string

```
hourController.text = durationhour.toString();
```

Comment: thanks for helping me!! but it is still an error flutter says error: The instance member 'hourController' can't be accessed in an initializer.

Comment: You have to use `hourController.text` and not `hourController`

Comment: Or please provide the code snippet for see how you're using this.

Comment: thanks! int.parse(hourController.text) worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the int.parse(string) method:

`var one = int.parse('your string');`